# Finding id generator in xml for jpa inside Spring container

Tags: java, spring, jpa, configuration

The entities use table id generator strategy:

```
@Id
@TableGenerator(name = "id_gen",
        table = "id_gen",
        pkColumnName = "gen_name",
        valueColumnName = "gen_val",
        pkColumnValue = "shared_id_generator", /*same as generator name by default*/
        initialValue = 10, /*0 by default*/
        allocationSize = 100 /*50 by default*/)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "id_gen")
private long id;
```

All entities use the same strategy and same generator, so I moved table generator defenition into jpa-mapping xml file. Location in maven project:

```
main/resources/db/jpa/orm.xml
```

The generator now is defined in the jpa-mapping xml file as:

```
<table-generator name="id_shared_generator"
                 table="id_gen"
                 pk-column-name="gen_name"
                 pk-column-value="shared_id_value"
                 value-column-name="gen_val"
                 initial-value="10"
                 allocation-size="100" />
```

Now entities have the following id field:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "id_shared_generator")
private long id;
```

I don't use the persistence.xml file at all, I configure entityManagerFactory instead:

```
    @Bean
    @DependsOn("liquibase")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfb = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emfb.setDataSource(dataSource);
//        emfb.setPersistenceXmlLocation("classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml");
        emfb.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"com.savdev.springmvcexample.domain"});
        emfb.setMappingResources("db/jpa/orm.xml");
        emfb.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
        emfb.setJpaProperties( new Properties(){{
            put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate");
            put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
            put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        }});
        emfb.setPersistenceUnitName("springmvcexample");
        return emfb;
    }
```

Now I'm getting the following exception when try to load spring application context:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class
>   path resource [spring/repository-config.xml]: Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default]
>   Unable to build EntityManagerFactory ... Caused by:
>   org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown Id.generator:
>   id_shared_generator

Please tell me, what am I doing wrong? 
Is it allowed to set additional jpa mapping xml file via the `emfb.setMappingResources("db/jpa/orm.xml");` invocation?

Comment: Are you sure that your mapping file location is correct? `main/resources/jpa/orm.xml` vs `db/jpa/orm.xml`?

Comment: main/resources/db/jpa/orm.xml - location in the folder. but the resources folder in the classpath, so I pass only the "db/jpa/orm.xml" string